# isotope doesn't reLayout when items are appended

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-isotope, ujs

I am trying to append new items to a container via ajax request on Rails ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maqra/2/) with explanation is provided below)

my js response I wrote is

```
var $newthumbs = "..new items..";
$('#homepage_thumbnails').append( $newthumbs );
$('#homepage_thumbnails').isotope( 'appended', $newthumbs );
```

I seem to have some sort of a problem once the new items are appended.. 
Once the items are appende, isotope doesn't seem to fire and I am left with items which were initially isotoped and the new items which are not isotoped.

this is an example of what I have (I got several isotoped items and then straight after several new unisotoped items)

```
<div id="homepage_thumbnails" class="thumbnails isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 720px;">
<div class="thumbnail-item isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 480px, 0px);">
...
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-item thumbnail span2">
    ...
</div>
</div>
```

note that is happens with `$('#homepage_thumbnails').isotope( 'insert', $newthumbs );` as well

What is going on here?

**Update**

It seems that isotope gets stuck somehow.. since if I put alert('test') after it, it won't get fired. If I put the alert beforethe isotope call, the alert gets fired... ahhh help

**Update 2**

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maqra/2/) that shows the problem. It is very simple, but I think the problem is simple as well - I'm just missing out on something important.

**jsfiddle explanation and how it related to my original problem:**

on the jsfiddle are 2 class - `item` and `red-item`. A simple layout of 3 items with transparent background (to show the problem better). Once `clickme` is clicked a `new-item` should join the group via append and then recombabulized with isotope. The result as seen is that the `red-item` is below the first `item` and doesn't get isotoped. Via inspect it can be seen that it is the same as my original problem which is that the original items get isotoped, yet the new appended items don't.

Hope I made it clear and that someone will be able to help me and prove me sane. Thank you.

**Update 3**

The solution (partial) is to engulf newthumbs with $() like so

```
var $newthumbs = $("..new items..");
```

however I still have a problem with this..

on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maqra/4/) I've added the solution and make is so 2 div are added each time.

on this [broken fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maqra/6/) I've added the divs similiar to how render helper does on Rails, which added \n \t and so forth. This doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to figure out how to make it work..

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem as you and I used your fiddle to find a solution. I think the problem is that after you append the new items you need to give isotope a reference to those inserted items.

http://jsfiddle.net/cR7WP/

When you say:

`element.append( '<div />' ).isotope( 'appended', $('<div />') )`

Two separate div elements are created; one that is actually appended and one that is a fragment, that Isotope tries to layout. The appended div never gets passed to the layout function.

Comment: Don't forget that "newItems" is a variable so it should be defined with a "var" keyword. Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 4):

I know that thread is old, but here is my solution. It seems isotope just can not immediately render the container:

```
var item = $(e);
setTimeout(function() {
  CSP.grid.append(item).isotope('appended', item);
}, 50); // fixes an overlay bug
```

Comment: this had been bugging me for years and it works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
$container = $('#browsecontainer');

$isotope = $container.isotope({
    getSortData: {
      },
      alphabetical: function( $elem ) {
        var name = $elem.find('.name'),
            itemText = name.length ? name : $elem;
        return itemText.text();
      }
    }
  });  


    //// to append items
    var isotopeData = $container.data('isotope');
    for(var item in items)
    {
            $newItem = $(items[item]);
            $container.append( $newItem ).isotope( 'appended', $newItem );
    }
```

///To relayout

```
  $container.isotope( options ,function(){

        //u can remove some items if u want
  });
```

items are bunch of divs

Here I'm adding multiple items, so I'm taking it in loop, $container is the reference of object

Comment: I don't understand how the for loop goes if my $newItems is a bunch of div tags

Comment: also, you made the appending incremental since you encountered a similiar problem as mine?

Comment: this causes the same issue for me.. Items get appended but isotop doesn't run on the